# What are some factors that could affect program runtime?

Tags: process, linux-kernel, profiling, scheduling

I'm doing some work on profiling the behavior of programs.  One thing I would like to do is get the amount of time that a process has run on the CPU.  I am accomplishing this by reading the *sum_exec_runtime* field in the Linux kernel's *sched_entity* data structure.

After testing this with some fairly simple programs which simply execute a loop and then exit, I am running into a peculiar issue, being that the program does not finish with the same runtime each time it is executed.  Seeing as *sum_exec_runtime* is a value represented in nanoseconds, I would expect the value to differ within a few microseconds.  However, I am seeing variations of several milliseconds.

My initial reaction was that this could be due to I/O waiting times, however it is my understanding that the process should give up the CPU while waiting for I/O.  Furthermore, my test programs are simply executing loops, so there should be very little to no I/O.

I am seeking any advice on the following:

1. Is *sum_exec_runtime* not the actual time that a process has had control of the CPU?
2. Does the process not actually give up the CPU while waiting for I/O?
3. Are there other factors that could affect the actual runtime of a process (besides I/O)?

Keep in mind, I am only trying to find the actual time that the process spent executing on the CPU.  I do not care about the total execution time including sleeping or waiting to run.

Edit: I also want to make clear that there are no branches in my test program aside from the loop, which simply loops for a constant number of iterations.

Thanks.

Comment: Expect noise in that measurement, especially in programs with short run time. All kinds of things can affect it. Do a large number of them and average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is really broad, but you can incur context switches for various reasons. Calling most system calls involves at least one context switch. Page faults cause contexts switches. Exceeding your time slice causes a context switch.

`sum_exec_runtime` is equal to `utime` + `stime` from `/proc/$PID/stat`, but `sum_exec_runtime` is measured in nanoseconds. It sounds like you only care about `utime` which is the time your process has been scheduled in user mode. See [proc(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) for more details.

You can look at `nr_switches` both voluntary and involuntary which are also part of `sched_entity`. That will probably account for most variation, but I would not expect successive runs to be identical. The exact time that you get for each run will be affected by all of the other processes running on the system.

You'll also be affected by the amount of file system cache used on your system and how many file system cache hits you get in successive runs if you are doing any IO at all.

To give a very concrete and obvious example of how other processes can affect the run time of the current process, think about if you are exceeding your physical RAM constraints. If your program asks for more RAM, then the kernel is going to spend more time swapping. That time swapping will be accounted in `stime` but will vary depending on how much RAM you need and how much RAM is available. There are lot's of other ways that other processes can affect your process's run time. This is just one example.

To answer your 3 points:

1. `sum_exec_runtime` is the actual time the scheduler ran the process *including* system time
2. If you count switching to the kernel as the process giving up the CPU, then yes, but it does not necessarily mean a different user process may get the CPU back once the kernel is done.
3. I think I've already answered this question that there are lot's of factors.

Comment: I'm assuming that you are referring to stime as sleep time? It was my understanding that sum_exec_runtime does not include the time spent sleeping.  If this is the case, however, I guess it is my implementation that is flawed.  Thanks for feedback.

Comment: `stime` is system time.

Comment: In the case of system time + user time, I do care about both.  I simply do not want to include any time spent sleeping or waiting to run.  I believe the time spent on the CPU should be the same regardless of the number of other processes running on the system.  It is the sleep time and the waiting time that should be variable depending on the number of processes.

Comment: This assumption is false. Your system has shared resources for which the other processes are competing.

Comment: Ok, based on your last edit, I can see now that I should probably just collect the utime.  I will do more research into how to do this.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just wanted to mention that after accounting for only utime, my profiling scheme is much more precise.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @b4hand What kind of operations are categorized as user time?

Comment: utime is defined in the link that I gave to the proc man page, but this is time your process has been scheduled in user mode or basically time spent running your application code.